# How can I use textbox value as parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send NumberBox Inputted values to the controller.

I can send the numberBox value to the controller in the bellow way

```
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetProductInReceipt", "Sale")?id=' + document.getElementById('SaleQuantity@(i)').value" />
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetProductInReceipt", "Sale")?id=' + $('#SaleQuantity@(i)').val()" />
```

Both ways send the NumberBox value from this code

but I need to send one more parameters to the controller which I can send seperately like this,

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetProductInReceipt", "Sale", new { productId = item.ProductId})">+</a>
```

How can I send both parameters together?
I need to send both parameters using any one way.

Here is my code

```
@{ var i = 0;}
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    @foreach (var item in Model) { 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)
                        </td>

                        <td>                                
                            <input type="number" class="numberInput" name="SaleQuantity@(i)" id="SaleQuantity@(i)" min="1">

                        <td>  <a href="@Url.Action("GetProductInReceipt", "Sale", new { productId = item.ProductId, saleQuantity = "here I need to put the value from NumberBox inout"})">+</a>

                        </td>
                            </tr>
                            i++;
                                }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I want to do it without ajax call. Simply how can I send both parameters together?

Comment: Did you tried this? <a href="@Url.Action("GetProductInReceipt", "Sale", new { productId = item.ProductId,id=" + $('#SaleQuantity@(i)').val()}+")">+</a>

Comment: Yea, I have tried with your code But it's not working!